# How to call a Rust function from JavaScript without a namespace?

Tags: javascript, rust

I am using the [stdweb library](https://github.com/koute/stdweb) to call a Rust function from JavaScript:

```
#[js_export]
fn handleClick(e: Value) {
    js!{ alert("Hello!"); }
}
```

It works, but I have to add the namespace `Module.exports.` to call it:

```
React.createElement("p",{onClick: e => Module.exports.handleClick(e) }, ... }
```

How can I hide this namespace or make it smaller?

Comment: Are you not familiar with JavaScript coding practices? There's nothing special about this code from the JS point of view, which is kind of the point.

Comment: I am making a DSL in Rust to create React components. They are created using JavaScript functions: `function Hello(props) {  return <h1>Hello!</h1>;}` is a component that can be used as `var elem = <Hello/>;`. When I create the component in Rust and use it in the same file I need to add the namespace. From another file, I can do `import { Hello } from './comp.js';` and use Hello without a namespace. I want to use Hello without a namespace in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't call a Rust function by name from JavaScript unless I exported it first (`#[js_export]`). However, the `js!` macro from the [stdweb library](https://github.com/koute/stdweb) allows JavaScript code to call a regular Rust function:

```
fn handleClick(e: Value) {
    js!{ alert("Hello!"); }
}
```

To call it:

```
js!{
    React.createElement("p",{onClick: @{handleClick} }, ...);
}
```

or, if you really need to name the function:

```
js!{
    const fct = @{handleClick};
    React.createElement("p",{onClick: fct}, ...);
```